# Math.random() not returning properly

Tags: java, variables, casting

I have this code where I want to return String word done randomly so a different string retuns each time. It works fine with

```
words = sentenceStore[rnd.nextInt(sentenceStore.length)];
```

But try using Math class method and it just returns the string of index 0 each time

```
words = sentenceStore[(int)Math.random() * sentenceStore.length];
```

Can anyone help?

WordBank.java (no main method here):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class WordBank  {

    private String [] sentenceStore; 

    public String getSentence (String words)  {   

        String [] sentenceStore = new String [5];  //i'll store 5 sentences here for now.

        sentenceStore[0] = "Hello how are you doing";
        sentenceStore[1] = "What do you want eh";
        sentenceStore[2] = "Hello can i help you"; 
        sentenceStore[3] = "You are so incredibly pretty";
        sentenceStore[4] = "What was that you said";

        Random rnd = new Random();

        words = sentenceStore[rnd.nextInt(sentenceStore.length)]; 

        //words = sentenceStore[(int)Math.random() * sentenceStore.length];

        return words;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast the whole thing to `int`, not only `Math.random()`

`(int)Math.random()` always returns 0. Then you multiply 0 with `sentenceStore.length`, which will result in 0, too.

Use

```
words = sentenceStore[(int) (Math.random() * sentenceStore.length)];
```